# cocoa - add NSTextfield to NSRect

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsrect

I'm confused as to why the code below isn't working, what I would like to achieve is to have a NSTextfield in a NSRect but I'm not sure if it's possible and if it is how to do it, I tried the code below but it's not working...

```
NSRect city_label = NSMakeRect(20, 20, 7, 7);

NSTextField *label = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:city_label];

label.stringValue = @"Contents of NSTextfield";
```

The NSRect gets drawn in an NSView

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSRect is not the sort of entity which could be "drawn in an `NSView`"--it is not an instance of a subview of `NSView`.  An NSRect is just a `C struct` describe size (width and height) and origin (x and y).

After initializing your `NSTextField` with its frame (keep in mind that the origin here is relative to the view to which you will add the text field as a subview), you must add it to the view that you want to have as its superview.  Assuming for a moment that we're in a custom subclass of NSViewController, your code just needs this additional line

```
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Thanks that helped I'm in a subclass of NSView, I think so I removed the `.view` from `[self.view addSubview:label];` and that worked